# How to add offset to TimedeltaIndex in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, offset, timedelta

How can I add an offset to an Panda Dataframe with a TimedeltaIndex?

```
dfN.index
```

Outputs:

```
TimedeltaIndex([       '00:00:00', '00:00:00.100000', '00:00:00.200000',
                '00:00:00.300000', '00:00:00.400000', '00:00:00.500000',
                '00:00:00.600000', '00:00:00.700000', '00:00:00.800000',
                '00:00:00.900000',
                ...
                '01:56:26.700000', '01:56:26.800000', '01:56:26.900000',
                       '01:56:27', '01:56:27.100000', '01:56:27.200000',
                '01:56:27.300000', '01:56:27.400000', '01:56:27.500000',
                '01:56:27.600000'],
               dtype='timedelta64[ns]', name='timestamps', length=69877, freq='100L')
```

This does not work:

```
dfN.index += Offset #Offset = 100
```

Outputs

```
TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with TimedeltaArray is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`
```

In this case the data is spaced in every 100miliseconds. And I would like to add and offset of 500miliseconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `Offset` can't be an integer. You need to create a Timedelta object to add it. Try this:

```
dfN.index += pd.Timedelta(100, unit=‘milliseconds’) #This will add 100 miliseconds
```

or

```
dfN.index += pd.Timedelta(milliseconds = 100)
```

Comment: or `pd.Timedelta(milliseconds=100)`. +1

Comment: @Corralien awesome, is it okay if I add this to the answer?

Comment: @MarK I’m glad it helped :)